# Missing library in tensorflow docker container

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I have received a backup from past engineer's docker container, which was a python app using tensorflow and hosted on online cloud (not sure which).

I'm currently trying to run it on a baremetal (Ubuntu 20.04 Server LTS)  at home for testing purposes using Tesla T4 GPU, docker already detected my GPU after running the nvidia-smi image with `--gpus all` option.

I imported the .tar using Portainer, Portainer was able to pick it up effortlessly, then I tried to create the container using the image. After exposing the port, then changing the runtime to nvidia + adding `/dev/nvidia0` to the devices menu, It was able to detect Tesla as the running GPU.

But then, after looking at the logs from Portainer (logs below), apparently some of the library was missing from the container. Is there any way for me to download these images from the container or download them to my server then reference it to the container?

I have tried downloading the cuda drivers to my server, changing the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH:` env of the container to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` which has *some* of the missing library (did not work), and both had failed to resolve the issue.

```
pciBusID: 0000:84:00.0 name: Tesla T4 computeCapability: 7.5

coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 14.75GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 298.08GiB/s

2021-12-08 08:12:05.674165: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1

2021-12-08 08:12:05.674345: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.10'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64

2021-12-08 08:12:05.674432: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcufft.so.10'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64

2021-12-08 08:12:05.674515: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcurand.so.10'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64

2021-12-08 08:12:05.674597: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.10'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64

2021-12-08 08:12:05.674680: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.10'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64

2021-12-08 08:12:05.674779: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.7'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64

2021-12-08 08:12:05.674796: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1753] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.

Skipping registering GPU devices...

2021-12-08 08:12:05.674814: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:

2021-12-08 08:12:05.674824: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 

2021-12-08 08:12:05.674832: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N
```

For additional information, my server's nvidia driver version is 460.106.00, my Docker version is 20.10.11, I already installed nvidia-container-toolkit, cuda 11.2, and the env of the image says cuda>=10.1

As for asking the previous developer, the person is no longer available.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For Tensorflow GPU support on Linux, install [NVIDIA Docker support](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker). Make sure you have followed all the steps mentioned on [Tensorflow.org](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker). Thanks!